# Tkinter Threading Issue: system() takes at most 1 argument (27 given)

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this code to install Pygame.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='gray90', relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()


def run_command(command):
    # for i in range (5):
    threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=f'cmd /c "{command}"').start()  # TypeError: system() takes at most 1
    # argument (27 given)


button1 = tk.Button(text='      Run Command      ', command=lambda: run_command("pip install pygame"), bg='green', fg='white',
                    font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

But it throws an error; TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (27 given)
I can do `os.system(f'cmd /c "{command}"')`, but the button freezes so I don't want that. How can I fix my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the "args" argument in threading.Thread expects a tuple.

Changing the line to `threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=(f'cmd /c "{command}"', )).start()`
fixes the issue.

Full code:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='gray90', relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()


def run_command(command):
    # for i in range (5):
    print(os.system)
    threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=(f'cmd /c "{command}"', )).start()  # TypeError: system() takes at most 1
    # argument (27 given)


button1 = tk.Button(text='      Run Command      ', command=lambda: run_command("pip install pygame"), bg='green', fg='white',
                    font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='gray90', relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()


def run_command(command):
    # for i in range (5):
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: os.system(command)).start()


button1 = tk.Button(text='      Run Command      ', command=lambda: run_command("pip install pygame"), bg='green', fg='white',
                    font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

try this and see.